# Username and password verification in a game

Tags: python, python-requests, passwords

I'm a beginner in coding and I need to do an assignment- I've tried to do the above task as planned but all I ended up doing was verifying a username. The task is for Player 2 and Player 2 to enter a username and password. If password is correct then the game starts- but I don't know how to start the game. Keeping in mind I'm just a ks3/GCSE student so my code will not be very high-level. Please may I have some help? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you can create a function around the game code. Than you add in over the function
username = input("Enter Username: ")
password = input("Enter password")

```
if username == Username and password == Password:
   game()
```